# How to execute code after 3rd party slide down animation?

Tags: javascript, materialize

**Background:**
I am using the [materialize](http://materializecss.com/) JS to create collapsible divs. When a div that has a class of collapsible-header is clicked, a slide down animation occurs on the sibling div that has a class of collapsible-body, showing the contents of the collapsible-body.

What I am trying to accomplish is when a collapsible header is clicked, the browser should scroll to the top of that div so that the contents are in full view of the user. I have used an on click event, which works fine on the first collapsible. But then, if you have an open collapsible and you click on another to open it, it doesn't scroll to the top of the clicked div properly (it will scroll to the middle of the body, or way above the top of the div).

JS Fiddle of on click functionality: https://jsfiddle.net/f83dct8f/4/

I am able to accomplish what I am looking to do by editing the Materialize JS itself. Here is how the line looks before my edit:

```js
object.siblings('.collapsible-body').stop(true, false).slideDown({
  duration: 350,
  easing: "easeOutQuart",
  queue: false,
  complete: function() {
    $(this).css('height', '');
  }
});
```

I add the following to the complete portion of the above statement to accomplish what I'm looking for:

```
$('body').animate({scrollTop: $('.collapsible-header.active').offset().top },'slow');
```

**Question:** I do not want to edit the Materialize 3rd party code to accomplish what I need, so I need to find a way to implement the body animate code after the slide down is finished, without editing the Materialize animation. I know there has to be a way to do it?

I have tried event queues on the collapsible body, which seemed promising, but my test console print executed during the animation. See below. If someone could point me in the right direction of what else I could try, I would greatly appreciate it.

```
$('.collapsible-header.active')
.siblings('.collapsible-body').slideDown().queue(function(){    

console.log('DONE');

});
```

Comment: Could you put up a jsFiddle with your scenario? It's a little hard to tell what's going on from text alone. Also, have you tried promises to keep your execution in the right order?

Comment: I have not tried promises, but I will certainly look into them more. Here is a JSFiddle of my scenario (with the buggy on click code so you can see why modification of the animation was necessary): https://jsfiddle.net/f83dct8f/4/

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the `onOpen` option when initialising your `.collapsible`. Pass in a function to execute when the accordion is opened. The function receives the element as a argument.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.collapsible').collapsible({
        onOpen: function(el) {
            $('body').animate({scrollTop: el.offset().top },'slow');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Oh, I did not even know this was an option. I will try it now.

Comment: This did not work, unfortunately. Nothing happened when the collapsible was opened, and there were no errors in the console. Thank you for your idea though!

Comment: I made a Codepen that seems to work ok. What version of Materialize are you using? https://codepen.io/MarkRabey/pen/eRzQoK

Comment: I apologize, I was using an older version. I updated materialize and the code executed, but if you open another collapsible without closing the other, it doesn't scroll to the top of the newly opened collapsible (example: open 'first', then open 'second'). That is a perfect demonstration of my problem. I think I have found a way around this using onClose, still playing around with it.